# Может ли внешний ключ содержать свои значения?

Tags: sql

Имеются 2 таблицы `First` и `Second`, у `First` одно поле а типа `int` (первичный ключ), а у `Second` 2 поля `b` типа `int` (первичный ключ) и `a` типа `int` (внешний ключ, ссылающийся на A(a)),

вопрос вот в чём: **может ли B(a) содержать свои собственные значения, которых нет в A(a)?**

и если да, то как написать такой запрос, т.к. через insert into выдаёт ошибку

> insert or update on table "b" violates foreign key constraint "fk_b$a"

Comment: у вас таблица `Second` ссылается посредством `foreign key` на таблицу 'First'. это в свою очередь означает что каждая запись в таблице `Second` в поле 'a' должна иметь конкретно значение с таблички 'First'.

у вас этого не наблюдается видимо потому что вы сначала делаете insert в таблицу 'Second', в то время как надо сначала вставить запись с соответсвующим значением 'a' в таблицу 'First', а потом уже в таблицу 'Second'

> может ли B(a) содержать свои собственные значения, которых нет в A(a)? 

нет не может, однако вы можете удалить констрейнт или отключить его - и то и другое неправильно

Comment: просто мне дали задание, увеличить все значения, которые не повторяются Second(a) в 2 раза, но Second(a) - это внешний ключ first(a), вот я и в затруднении как тут быть

Comment: @jmu"Напишите запрос, который увеличит значения столбца "a" в
таблице Second в 2 раза только для тех строк, где значение столбца "а"
уникально в таблице Second."

Answer (score 1):

у вас таблица Second ссылается посредством foreign key на таблицу 'First'. это в свою очередь означает что каждая запись в таблице Second в поле 'a' должна иметь конкретно значение с таблички 'First'. у вас этого не наблюдается видимо потому что вы сначала делаете insert в таблицу 'Second', в то время как надо сначала вставить запись с соответсвующим значением 'a' в таблицу 'First', а потом уже в таблицу 'Second' > может ли B(a) содержать свои собственные значения, которых нет в A(a)? нет не может, однако вы можете удалить констрейнт или отключить его - и то и другое неправильно

Answer (score 0):

Не может, по-идее. На то и нужны внешние ключи с контролем целостности.

Comment: просто дали задание увеличить в 2 раза только уникальные значение B(a), а B(a) является внешним ключом A(a)

Comment: @stepofchange
Что-то вы с преподом друг друга не поняли)Возможно, имелось в виду, уникальные значения a в таблице  B

Comment: все же один частый случай есть, когда при наличии внешнего ключа можно добавить запись, в связанном поле которого данные не соответствуют данным таблицы, на которую ссылается внешний ключ
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3986/1

Comment: @Free_ze, да именно то, что вы написали в первом комменте, именно это и нужно сделать, но а в таблице B и есть внешний ключ к A(a)

Comment: A и B - это таблицы First и second

Answer (score 0):

Удали внешний ключ и пиши туда, что хочешь. Внешний ключ накладывает такие ограничения.

Comment: очень плохая практика так делать, лучше не ставить ограничение сразу (FK - это ограничение а не связь), связать данные джойном, можно и без ключа